# How does a site write to just the inspector?

Tags: browser, web

In order to notify users of the https://facebook.com/selfxss scam, FB put the following message in the developer console:

```
"



 .d8888b.  888                       888    
d88P  Y88b 888                       888    
Y88b.      888                       888    This is a browser feature intended for 
 "Y888b.   888888  .d88b.  88888b.   888    developers. If someone told you to copy-paste 
    "Y88b. 888    d88""88b 888 "88b  888    something here to enable a Facebook feature 
      "888 888    888  888 888  888  Y8P    or "hack" someone's account, it is a 
Y88b  d88P Y88b.  Y88..88P 888 d88P         scam and will give them access to your 
 "Y8888P"   "Y888  "Y88P"  88888P"   888    Facebook account.
                           888              
                           888              
                           888              

See https://www.facebook.com/selfxss for more information.
"
```

I would assume this would be done with `console.log()`, but when I search FB page source for a `console.log` command I see nothing.

How else might they have done it?

Comment: It'll be in the javascript, which you may not be able to read locally due to obfuscation and other things.

Comment: It can even be as simple as something like `blah = console; blah.log("message");`

Comment: thanks @Barmar @djsmiley2k. I notice they label a lot of classes things like `._4jl2`, so yeah it makes sense that a `console.log()` would not be readable.